# Global Ruby HTTP Timeout

Tags: ruby

We are having some timeout issues. We are running sidekiq with multiple threads. Each of them perform some http operations. Sometimes the workers are getting stuck in a Net HTTP call, without throwing a timeout. Then all threads idle and do nothing anymore.

- The http `read_timeout` seems to to be set to 60, whereas the ruby default `open_timeout` is set to `nil`. Could this be the issue?
- If yes, is it possible to set a default value of the timeout for all instances of the http class? Monkey patch it?

**Stacktrace:**

```
2014-07-07T07:59:22Z 26495 TID-otmt0zt9s INFO: /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `open'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `block in connect'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/timeout.rb:76:in `timeout'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:878:in `connect'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:863:in `do_start'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:852:in `start'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:1369:in `request'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.1/lib/patches/net_patches.rb:7:in `block in request_with_mini_profiler'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.1/lib/mini_profiler/profiling_methods.rb:40:in `step'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.9.1/lib/patches/net_patches.rb:6:in `request_with_mini_profiler'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rest-client-1.6.7/lib/restclient/net_http_ext.rb:51:in `request'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:80:in `perform_request'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/adapter/net_http.rb:39:in `call'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/faraday-0.9.0/lib/faraday/request/url_encoded.rb:15:in `call'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/signet-0.5.0/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:875:in `fetch_access_token'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/signet-0.5.0/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:898:in `fetch_access_token!'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/signet-0.5.0/lib/signet/oauth_2/client.rb:913:in `refresh!'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/google-ads-common-0.9.5/lib/ads_common/auth/oauth2_handler.rb:91:in `refresh_token!'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/google-ads-common-0.9.5/lib/ads_common/auth/oauth2_handler.rb:83:in `get_token'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/google-ads-common-0.9.5/lib/ads_common/auth/oauth2_handler.rb:75:in `auth_string'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/google-ads-common-0.9.5/lib/ads_common/savon_headers/oauth_header_handler.rb:45:in `generate_headers'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/google-ads-common-0.9.5/lib/ads_common/savon_headers/base_header_handler.rb:75:in `prepare_request'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/google-ads-common-0.9.5/lib/ads_common/savon_service.rb:103:in `block in execute_soap_request'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-1.2.0/lib/savon/client.rb:129:in `yield_objects'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-1.2.0/lib/savon/client.rb:122:in `process'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-1.2.0/lib/savon/client.rb:84:in `block in request'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-1.2.0/lib/savon/soap/request_builder.rb:56:in `call'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-1.2.0/lib/savon/soap/request_builder.rb:56:in `request'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/savon-1.2.0/lib/savon/client.rb:86:in `request'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/google-ads-common-0.9.5/lib/ads_common/savon_service.rb:101:in `execute_soap_request'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/google-ads-common-0.9.5/lib/ads_common/savon_service.rb:80:in `execute_action'
/home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/google-adwords-api-0.11.1/lib/adwords_api/v201402/campaign_service.rb:25:in `mutate'
/home/deployer/apps/robot/lib/adwords_helper.rb:1355:in `toggle_campaign'
/home/deployer/apps/robot/app/models/adwords_campaign.rb:262:in `adwords_toggle'
/home/deployer/apps/robot/app/workers/update_campaign_status.rb:13:in `perform'
/home/deployer/apps/robot/app/workers/recurring/refresh_campaign_status.rb:12:in `block in perform'
```

**Edit:**

I monkey patched the http library. Not sure if the problem will occur again. If yes I will post here.

```
module Net
  class HTTP < Protocol
    alias_method :old_initialize, :initialize

    def initialize(address, port = nil, open_timeout: 60)
      old_initialize(address, port)
      self.open_timeout = open_timeout
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be right to self answer your question to close it?

Comment: Can you please move the answer out of the question and into an answer, and then give it the checkmark?  This will help others who are having the same problem (it's easier to see that a question has an answer when it's not in the question itself).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the default timeout values in `Net::HTTP`, as you posted in your update. For Ruby 2.1.0 the default value for [`open_timeout`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/net/2.1.0/Net/HTTP#open_timeout-instance_method) is `nil`. [`read_timeout`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/net/2.1.0/Net/HTTP#read_timeout-instance_method) safely defaults to 60s.

As of Ruby 2.3 the default value for `open_timeout` [has changed from `nil` to 60s](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/net/2.3.1/Net/HTTP#open_timeout-instance_method). Ruby 2.3 would not be released for another year and a half after you originally asked this question, but my recommendation to you or anyone else experiencing this issue would be to upgrade to Ruby 2.3 or higher. (and not monkeypatch the core library, if possible)